# Как загрузить значение в Yii1 для MANY-TO-MANY зависимости

Tags: php, yii

У нас есть таблица bookings (id, ...), bookingsTourists (t_id, link), и bookingsTouristsBookings (id, t_id, linkedTo). Используя связь в модели Booking, я могу получить туристов через вот такое отношение в функции relations():

```
'tourists' => array (
     MANY_MANY,
     'BookingTourist',
     'bookingsTouristsBookings(bookingId, bookingsTouristId)',
)
```

Вопрос вот в чем - как я могу присвоить туристам брони значение link значению linkedTo? То есть при загрузке модели в ->tourists, как я могу записать значение из bookingsTouristBookings в boookingsTourists? Есть ли в Yii1 какие-либо специальные подходы или методы, callback'и или что-то в этом роде? Я знаю что есть afterFind в BookingTourist, но там я не знаю booking->id, к тому же он не вызывается при доступе через $booking->tourists.

Comment: В итоге было найдено решение - использование __get  и проверка названия переменной, но это было очень криво, так как в многих случаях в коде при доступу к этому массиву было непонятно, для записи это или для чтения. Если я прав, то если переменная - массив, и делается [] = значение, то сначала делается операция get, а уже потом операция присвоения/добавления? Или нет? Надо будет проверить.

Answer (score 0):

какой-то observer надо делать который следит за событием и срабатывает при загрузке в ->tourists. Я не до конца понимаю может суть, не помогут тут методы типа beforeXXXX()? Если нет то вероятно тогда самописный observer какой-то нет? 
Или вот behavior экстеншен вроде таких:
http://www.yiiframework.com/extension/save-relations-ar-behavior/#hh3
и вот
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14710068/yii-saving-many-many-many-relationships

Comment: Вызывается afterFind в модели BookingTourist но там у меня нет доступа к значению Booking, вызывавшего эту связь